# unnest queries in Wikidata with SPARQL

Tags: sql, sparql, wikidata, wikidata-query-service

I am trying to get a table from Wikidata with businesses, their twitter handle and the country of the business.

I am running the following query on https://query.wikidata.org/

```
SELECT *
WHERE {
  # querying for records where "instance of" (P31) = "business" (Q4830453)
  {?item wdt:P31 wd:Q4830453.
  OPTIONAL {?item rdfs:label ?name filter (lang(?name) = "en") .}
  OPTIONAL {?item p:P2002 ?twitter . ?twitter pq:P6552 ?twId .} # twitter user_id
  OPTIONAL { ?item wdt:P452 ?industry . } # industry 
  OPTIONAL { ?item wdt:P17 ?country . } # country 
  
} }
limit 100
```

and it returns something like this

```
item      name      twSn              twId           industry    country
wd:Q2283  Microsoft OpenAtMicrosoft   wd:Q880371     wd:Q880371  wd:Q30
wd:Q3884  Amazon    ....
....      ....
```

while for the twitter username and twitter id I actually get an output, for industry and country I get another Wikidata link (for instance clicking on wd:30 it leads to https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q30 which is the wikidata page for USA, and if i click on wd:Q880371 it goes to https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q880371  which is software industry).

How can I return the actual industry and the country instead of the links to their Wikidata pages such that the output looks more like this?

```
item      name      twSn              twId           industry             country
wd:Q2283  Microsoft OpenAtMicrosoft   wd:Q880371     software industry    USA
wd:Q3884  Amazon    ....
....      ....
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Wikidata’s `wikibase:label` utility:

```
SELECT ?item ?itemLabel ?twId ?industryLabel ?countryLabel
WHERE {
  
  # querying for records where "instance of" (P31) = "business" (Q4830453)
  ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q4830453 .

  OPTIONAL { 
    ?item p:P2002 ?twitter . 
    ?twitter pq:P6552 ?twId . # twitter user_id
  } 
  OPTIONAL { ?item wdt:P452 ?industry . } # industry 
  OPTIONAL { ?item wdt:P17 ?country . } # country 
  
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" . }
  
}
LIMIT 10
```

This `SERVICE` line tries to look up the English label for each variable ending in `Label`, and which has a corresponding counterpart without the suffix: `?country` → `?countryLabel` etc.

---

In general (e.g., when not using Wikidata), the usual way to solve your case would be to output the value of a suitable property (typically `rdfs:label`) of the item in question. So essentially what you did with your `?item`.